# Create an Aspect with AJDT in former Java Project

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, eclipse-kepler, ajdt

I decided to handle a problem in a Java project with AOP, so I installed AJDT 2.2.3 in my Eclipse Kepler. Everything seemed to work fine, as I can create a new AspectJ project and create aspects and everything works as it should. Aspects are properly woven and execute as I expected. After that I tried to integrate AspectJ in my already existing Java project. I converted it by using `Configure > Convert to AspectJ Project`. Still everything works fine, but when I come to the point of actually create an aspect in this project using the create aspect wizard, I encounter the folling error message:
`Creation of element failed. See error log for more details.` I can still finish the wizard, but the created aspect file looks different to the aspect files created in my first attempts in a AspectJ Project.

[image: File]

If I edit the created file, the same aspect that worked in the first try in a original AspectJ Project don't seem to have any effect.

The log message (some lines in between omitted):

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard.performFinish(NewElementWizard.java:134)
...
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.wizards.AJNewTypeWizardPage.ajc$interMethod$org_eclipse_ajdt_internal_ui_wizards_AJNewTypeWizardPage$org_eclipse_ajdt_internal_ui_wizards_NewTypeWizardPage$createAJType(AJNewTypeWizardPage.aj:267)
at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.ajc$interMethodDispatch2$org_eclipse_ajdt_internal_ui_wizards_AJNewTypeWizardPage$createAJType(NewTypeWizardPage.java:1)
at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.wizards.AJNewTypeWizardPage.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_eclipse_ajdt_internal_ui_wizards_AJNewTypeWizardPage$org_eclipse_ajdt_internal_ui_wizards_NewTypeWizardPage$createAJType(AJNewTypeWizardPage.aj)
...
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5331)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Does anybody know what this error wants to tell me and what I can do to use aspects in my project?

Comment: This looks like a case for the *aspectj-users* mailing list, possibly even for Bugzilla. But try the list first.

Answer (score 0):

Not for `Kepler`, but encountered similar problem on `Oxygen`. Created a Java project, converted it to `AspectJ` and later to `Maven` only to encounter the issue mentioned above. Scrapped it, created a new `Maven` project and converted it to `AspectJ`. That worked.